sed/awk expression to prepend text and append increasing numbers to list
I want to convert this list:
DISPATCH_C
HELLO_C
INTERFACES_C
LIST_C

to this list:
#define LOG_FILE_DISPATCH_C         1
#define LOG_FILE_HELLO_C            2
#define LOG_FILE_INTERFACES_C       3
#define LOG_FILE_LIST_C             4

How can I do this using sed or awk?  I thought it would be something like
sed -En '/(.*)/#define LOG_FILE_\1   {=;p;}/'

but that just gives me an error.  Apparently sed is interpreting the "#define" as a command and I don't know how to fix that.

You can may use this awk solution:
awk '{printf "#define LOG_FILE_%-30s%d\n", $1, NR}' file

#define LOG_FILE_DISPATCH_C                    1
#define LOG_FILE_HELLO_C                       2
#define LOG_FILE_INTERFACES_C                  3
#define LOG_FILE_LIST_C                        4


Regarding your original code
sed -En '/(.*)/#define LOG_FILE_\1   {=;p;}/'

in GNU sed # is command

A comment, until the next newline.

but you are attempting to apply to only certain lines, which does not make sense. Your command seems like maimed substitution (s) to add text before line, to do it correctly, if file.txt content is
DISPATCH_C
HELLO_C
INTERFACES_C
LIST_C

do
sed -n -e 's/\(.*\)/#define LOG_FILE_\1/' -e 'p' file.txt

which will give result
#define LOG_FILE_DISPATCH_C
#define LOG_FILE_HELLO_C
#define LOG_FILE_INTERFACES_C
#define LOG_FILE_LIST_C

Now we can attempt adding number
sed -n -e 's/\(.*\)/#define LOG_FILE_\1/' -e 'p' -e '=' file.txt

which will give
#define LOG_FILE_DISPATCH_C
1
#define LOG_FILE_HELLO_C
2
#define LOG_FILE_INTERFACES_C
3
#define LOG_FILE_LIST_C
4

As = does

Print the current input line number (with a trailing newline)

We are unable to do anything in it. It is however possible to ram that output into 2nd sed that is
sed -n -e 's/\(.*\)/#define LOG_FILE_\1/' -e 'p' -e '=' file.txt | sed -n -e '1~2h' -e '0~2{H;g;y/\n/ /;p}'

which gives output
#define LOG_FILE_DISPATCH_C 1
#define LOG_FILE_HELLO_C 2
#define LOG_FILE_INTERFACES_C 3
#define LOG_FILE_LIST_C 4

Explanation: for odd lines ram line into hold (h), for even lines append newline and line to hold (H), then set line to content of hold (g), translate line (y) replacing every newline (\n) with space, print (n) line. Observe that in result in always having one space before number. I am unable to coerce GNU sed to tabulate that, but I am not sed ninja. If you must have certain numbers of spaces AT ANY PRICE then it is better to use awk as already shown in other answer.
(tested in GNU sed 4.8)

# is standard and not GNU-specific: [0addr]# Ignore the '#' and the remainder of the line (treat them as a comment), with the single exception that if the first two characters in the script are "#n", the default output shall be suppressed; this shall be the equivalent of specifying -n on the command line. - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

With your shown samples please try following awk code. Using awk + column combination here.
awk '{print "#define LOG_FILE" $0,FNR}' Input_file | column -t

